# When launching cgminer with scrypt parameters, Windows gives an error message. Why does this occur?

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, scrypt, dogecoin

Cgminer opens up, stays for like a second or two and then Windows gives me an error message. Mining (bitcoins?) without --scrypt works fine but with the scrypt parameter, I get the message seen in the window below.

[image: cgminer with scrypt]

The settings for the .bat file are also in the image and I think they've been configured correctly. I tried uninstalling, installing different drivers. Read somewhere that the new ones don't work (tried with the latest drivers already) so I installed Catalyst 12.2 Beta (GPU is a Radeon HD 6670, Driver Version: 9.10.8.0 according to device manager) and it still doesn't work.

Help? :(

Comment: I have ran into the issue that after mining bitcoins my card will not mine scrypt without a full reboot of the system.  Not sure what causes this but try it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Checkout https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison and see what settings are working for other folks particularly the settings that tbenz9 mentions (intensity and thread concurrency)  also included with cgminer is a SCRYPT readme that will tell you the steps to follow to tweak these settings.

Comment: Shaders! Including the appropriate shaders value for your GPU does wonders! And yes, sometimes, after passing the miner a set of params that crash it, the GPU gets "stuck" in a bad state - you need to cold-reboot. So yes, reduce intensity and threads, set an appropriate shaders value, and cold-reboot just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem a few times, it could be just about anything unfortunately.  I would try changing your thread concurrency, and intensity values.  Some people have also recommended different drivers.